# Update CursorAdapter from asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-cursoradapter

I have an issue with notifying CursorAdapter the Data been changed.

```
    public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return new MyListCursorLoader(getActivity());
        }


        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            MyCursorAdapter adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(getActivity(),(MyCursor)cursor);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private static class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    ... some code ...

    }

    private static class MyListCursorLoader extends SQLiteCursorLoader {

    ... code ...

    }
```

SQLite database updates with AsyncTask (has public interface and ListFragment implements it with listener) and I try to refresh ListAdapter with onPostExecute, but I really don't know how.

AsyncTask code

```
public class MyDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public interface OnMyDownloaded {
        void onMyDownloaded();
    }


    public JSONDownloader(Context context, OnMyDownloaded listener) {

            ...code...

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ...code...
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listener.onMyDownloaded();
    }
```

Please, help me understand what should I do in MyListFragment inner class

```
private class OnEventDownloaded implements OnJSONDownloaded {
    ?????
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(int id, Bundle args, LoaderCallbacks<D> callback);`
It will call onCreateLoader, so loader will be recreated. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: It was the first thing I have tried. But callbacks implemented in fragment and called like `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);`, but how should I call callbacks from inner class?

Comment: I got how. I asked for a callback from the asynctask constructor: `public MyDownloader(Context context, LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> callback, OnMyDownloaded listener) {
  
  ...code...
 }`

and called `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, callback);` from listener (but I think it will work from onPostExecute too).